# Sorting one array and two others array follow

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Suppose we have three arrays `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
int a[1000] = {3,1,5,4};
int b[1000] = {7,9,11,3};
char c[1000] = {'A','B','C','D'};
```

Array `a` is then sorted, so it becomes:

```
a == {1,3,4,5}
```

Is it possible to arrange for the other two arrays to have their elements rearranged by index, so that they mirror the placement of the sorted elements in the sorted array `a`? In this example, this should result in

```
b == {9,7,3,11}
c == {'B','A','D','C'}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why `x[1000]` when just using 4 elements?

Comment: Not related, but you need to enclose your chars in `'`s: `char c[1000] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}` (unless they are `char` variables defined elsewhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a class `ABC`, which will hold 3 fields: int a, int b, char c.

implement the `operator<` for this class, and create a `ABC[]` of the approppriate size and populate it such that `ABC[i] = ABC(a[i],b[i],c[i])`.

implement the `operator<` so it will compare only `a`, and use sort on the ABC array.

after done sorting, you have all your elements in the desired order, just iterate the ABC array and populate the other arrays.

**EDIT:**

simplified [and hard coded] code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class ABC { 
public: 
  int a,b;
  char c;
  bool operator<(const ABC& other) const { 
    return a < other.a;
  }
};
int main() { 
  int a[4] = {3,1,5,4};
  int b[4] = {7,9,11,3};
  char c[4] = {'A','B','C','D'};
  ABC abc[4];
  for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++) { 
    abc[i].a = a[i];
    abc[i].b = b[i];
    abc[i].c = c[i];
  }
  sort(abc,abc+4);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    a[i] = abc[i].a;
    b[i] = abc[i].b;
    c[i] = abc[i].c;
  }
  cout << "a= [" << a[0] << ", " << a[1] << ", " << a[2] << ", " << a[3] << "]" << endl;
  cout << "b= [" << b[0] << ", " << b[1] << ", " << b[2] << ", " << b[3] << "]" << endl;
  cout << "c= [" << c[0] << ", " << c[1] << ", " << c[2] << ", " << c[3] << "]" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

works good for me on codepad: http://codepad.org/eCyNkyqR

Comment: can you show me code example, cause i am new so don't really understand that

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you need, but you can achieve similar results by using std::map and std::sort:

```
std::map<int, std::pair<int, char> > someArray;
```